# How can I compile and install multiple copies of gcc into /usr/local and have the binaries in /usr/local/bin reflect their version?

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning, gcc4

I'd like to have a couple different gcc versions. Most of the stuff gets created into its own version directory and installed there. However, the binaries sometimes just install as "gcc" or "gcc-ar" in /usr/local/bin when they should probably be a symlink to their corresponding version, such as gcc points to 12.1.0, which I can later change to 13.2.0, etc...

Is there a way to install this way?

gcc questions about installation and compiling options